# 2 icons for keyboard switch on gnome panel in Gnome Shell 3

Tags: 11.10, gnome, keyboard-layout

I have 2 icon do the same think (switch keyboard layout) in Ubuntu 11.10/GnomeShell.
I think it is because I  whitelist whole systray-area. Icon in systray (num. 1 on picture) consume much space and I like remove it. It is posible? 
screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/805747)

Michael Milligan (milli) instructions how to apply the patch for gnome-settings-daemon

```
apt-get source gnome-settings-daemon
sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-settings-daemon
sudo apt-get install devscripts build-essential fakeroot patch    patchutils
cd gnome-settings-daemon-3.2.1
wget https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/805747/+attachment/2544403/+files/0001-change.patch
patch -p1 < 0001-change.patch
debuild -uc -us -b
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i gnome-settings-daemon_3.2.1-*
sudo killall gnome-settings-daemon
```

gsd-keyboard-kbd applet should be GONE.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.